# Advice re: information flow in combining PHP and JS?

Tags: php, javascript, workflow, referenceerror

Conceptually, this seems like it should be pretty simple, but I keep finding myself in a catch-22 whenever I try to implement it.  (Also, for a variety of reasons, I'd really like to handle this without jQuery or AJAX, if possible.)

On the client side, onload triggers a video to play and a picture to appear. Then, each time the user presses the space bar, a different video plays, until a certain point at which the spacebar triggers the next page to load.

On the server side, PHP arrays control which videos and pictures will be displayed (both the order within a page, as well as which set of videos, out of a total of 70 sets).

Currently, all the client-side action is controlled by a set of JS functions that are included in my html header.  All the PHP functions are listed toward the bottom of my main page script.  The kicker, though, is that the JS functions necessarily contain some PHP references.  For example:

```
document.getElementById("ImagePort").innerHTML="<img src=Pictures/<? echo $_SESSION['TrialArray'][4] . ">"; ?>";
```

The issue here isn't the syntax; it's the information flow sequence.  The problem is that when these PHP calls are in the header, they appear before the browser makes it to the part where I call the PHP function that assigns values to them.  PHP then throws error messages that muck up the JS parsing.

So then the intuitive solution is to either move these JS functions lower down (to a footer, perhaps) or else call the PHP functions before the header loads.  However, moving them to the footer didn't solve the problem for me.  I sortof thought it would... am I mistaken in that expectation, or have I perhaps made a simple mistake somewhere?

Moving the calls such that they precede the JS function definitions is equally problematic, since then the script doesn't know what the JS functions are called, either by PHP or in HTML.

PHP example: playVid(source) is a JS function, $Instructions is a PHP variable.

```
if ($_SESSION['Page'] == 0) {
            echo "<script>playVid(" . "'" . $Instructions . "'" . ");</script>";
        }
```

HTML example: both setFocus() and ShowFirstStimulus() are JS functions.

```
<body onload="setFocus(); ShowFirstStimulus()">
```

Both of these throw an "Uncaught Reference Error: [function] not defined.  Again, I'm trying to figure out whether that's because I simply *can't* do it this way, or if I've just made a mistake in how I've set it up.

Assuming that there really is no way out of this Catch-22 (where PHP functions can't be called before JS functions, and JS functions can't be called before PHP functions), it seems that one remaining option is to simply write some dummy code in which I initialize some PHP variables to some value that's bogus but parse-able.  This seems like terrible coding hygiene, but at this point I'm not seeing many other options.  Any suggestions?

Please also let me know if I need to clarify anything.  Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery and AJAX?

Comment: Do you understand that _all_ the PHP in your page is executed _before_ the page is even sent to the browser? So, if your PHP code relies on anything from javascript, that information has to be sent back to the server.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that.  (Fair question!)  So I can see why it's a problem to put PHP variables inside the JS functions before those variables have values.  What I *don't* yet understand is why it's not sufficient to simply move the JS functions down on the page such that they appear *after* the relevant PHP functions have assigned values to those variables. 

Oh, and the "problem" with jQuery and AJAX is just that when I leave this project in a few weeks, I'm handing it over to someone who knows even less about this stuff than I do, so I'm trying to keep things as transparent as possible.

Comment: Also, to clarify again, none of the PHP relies on the javascript.  Rather, the javascript relies on the PHP, which is a perfectly appropriate dependency, yes? The issue is just about the position and sequence in which I need to place and call the various functions in order to achieve my desired result.

Comment: Yes, that's an appropriate dependency. What you're attempting to do is done all the time, so it must be in the way you're constructing your HTML page. However, short of seeing the code I don't see how anyone can help. This underlies the reason we moved to [separation of concerns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/98765/911182). If the person you're handing it off to knows little about this stuff, all the better reason not to give them spaghetti IMHO.

Comment: Thanks- I just needed the confirmation that there was nothing wrong with my logic.  The good news is that it's now working: all PHP variables are assigned to values *above* the point at which my header file (which houses my JS functions) is included.  The less-good news is that I can't identify the exactly problem that caused this solution to not work when I tried it before, but I can live with that for now.  Thanks for your help!